# Effects of magnetic fields overs biological life

Tags: biology, physics, electromagnetism

How would life evolve on a planet or other place with a high magnetic field? (It should be a field strong enough to attract tools and weapons and stick them to the ground.) The life forms that would live there (including humans) will have to use cooper tools, so the field must be of 5 Teslas at least).

Comment: As asked, this is too broad.  Even if you boil it down to just two questions (can life biologically evolve on a planet with a 1 tesla magnetosphere, and can life develop metal tools past the copper age on such a world?), it's still two broad (SE's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer).  As written, this question could reasonably require volumes of books to answer.  I'm happy to retract my too-broad vote if you edit your question down to a single, specific question.

Comment: I tried to get specific detail to what I want answered but ok, boss.

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question, but ask for one more piece of information.  What do you consider a high magnetic field?  Humans survive MRIs just fine, and MRIs tend to be 0.5-3.0 Tesla.  However, I don't know if there would be long-term effects if the techs walked away and came back in a week (so to speak).  I'm not sure at what magnetic strength the electrics in the human brain stop working or that would affect the iron in our biology.

Comment: @JBH - The patient would be deaf - MRIs are very noisy.

Comment: This is why I wrote it should be a field strong enough to attract tools and weapons and stick them to the ground. The life forms that would live there (including humans) will have to use indeed cooper tools so the field must be of 5 Teslas atleast. Should I put it in the question?

Comment: @EdwardConstantin, yes.  Please include all details in the question.  Remember, things are attracted to magnetic poles, not the sides of the magnet.  Therefore, nothing will ever snap to the ground.  But magnetic materials would align themselves along the magnetic field lines.  If you threw an iron rod into the air, it would snap to the field alignment - then fall to the ground per the planetary gravity.  Compasses would be remarkably accurate.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK.   :-)  Now, now, we're only talking about the magnetics.

Comment: I really want to take into consideration all the things before I start writing :))))))

Comment: I do not think this question is too broad now as if I gave too many information you would say it is not ok and if I give too little you say that it is not a good question. I want to know how animals and maybe fauna would look in, lets say 500 years from now if a strong magnetic field would be emitted by Terra (would animals be smaller/ bigger)

Comment: I don't know; I think your question is still pretty broad!  I mean "how" questions over a period of four or five billion years make for lots of ways evolution can go. Magnetic fields or no.

Comment: I am only interested in the effects of magnetic fields overs biological life. I already think of others changes based on the action of the world.

Comment: @Edward Constantin Copper tools - in such a strong magnetic field, every time one was moved around, it would move just fine in any direction but it would resist being twisted across the field lines and would generate such high internal eddy currents that it would melt. Hellava weird place to swordfight.

Comment: @EdwardConstantin maybe change the title of the question to that then?